# Issues with rigging pulling on the wrong vertexes, even though they aren't bonded to the bone

Tags: modeling, rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights, weight-paint-mode

I am trying to model and sculpt a medium poly character that has a fully rigged body and clothes. I am having this issue though. The mesh is properly parented and the weights were assigned with a data transfer from the body. I have tried to clean up the weights as much as possible but I'm still getting this issue where the rig will pull on faces that aren't even painted for that bone. The back faces of the hoodie are being pulled through the front faces and im not sure why because they are completely blue for every bone. I am pulling out my hair because of this problem, can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode if you select one vertex you can read its weights assignements in the "N" properties panel, vertex weights tab, so to understand which are the uncorrect assignements. Be aware that if a vertex has weights assigements to one vertex group/bone only it will follow that bone rigidly, even if the weight is 0.0001 (and looks blue in weight paint mode).

In weight paint mode you can also go to viewport overlays and change zero weights from "None" to "Active"  to better separate the black vertices (no weight) from blue vertices (some weight).